# celery+rabbitmq empty queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery+rabbitmq. I can't find convenient way to clear queue in celery+rabbitmq. I do it with remove and create vhost.

```
rabbitmqctl delete_vhost <vhostpath>
rabbitmqctl  add_vhost <vhostpath>
```

Is it prefer way to clear some celery queue ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how celery works, but I suspect you want to purge a RabbitMQ queue (you're currently simulating this by deleting the queues and having celery re-create them).

You could install RabbitMQ's [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).  Its WebUI will allow you to purge the required queue.  This should also tell you which queue you're aiming for, so you wouldn't need to delete everything.

Once you know which queue it is, you could purge it programatically.  For instance, using [py-amqplib](http://barryp.org/software/py-amqplib/), you would do something like:

```
from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp

conn = amqp.Connection(host="localhost:5672", userid="guest", password="guest", virtual_host="/", insist=False)
conn = conn.channel()
conn.queue_purge("the-target-queue")
```

There's probably a better way to do it, though.

Comment: conn.queue_purge doesn't work for me.  Is that an amqplib method?

Comment: Yes.  Check the docs and this tutorial: http://blogs.digitar.com/jjww/2009/01/rabbits-and-warrens/

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this problem because you used rabbitmq for the result backend and as a result you got too many queues, then i would suggest using a different result backend (redis or mongodb)

This is one well known flaw with the celery. It will create a separate queue for each result if you amqp for result backend.

If you still want to stick to amqp as result backend. It will clear itself in 24 hours. You can however set it to a smaller value using  `CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete ALL items in queue (especially when the list is long)

1) Saves all items into the file

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p /yourvhost name > queues.txt
```

don't forget to remove first and last lines from 'queues.txt'

2) Use mentioned python code to do the job

```
from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp

conn = amqp.Connection(host="127.0.0.1:5672", userid="guest", password="guest", virtual_host="/yourvhost", insist=False)
conn = conn.channel()

queues = None
with open('queues.txt', 'r') as f:
    queues = f.readlines()

for q in queues:
    if q:
        #print 'deleting %s' % q
        conn.queue_purge(q.strip())

print 'purged %d items' % len(queues)
```